# PID 0 System Idle Process Monitoring

Tags: windows

How can a User Application monitor PID=0 for its percentage?

OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,false,0) Returns Error 5: Access is Denied.

Is there a performance API, or ?? to query PID=0?

Comment: you can not got error 5: Access is Denied here. 0 - this is invalid pid. you must got `STATUS_INVALID_CID` here (converted to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) if you try open *system* process instead - you can do this with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` only, if you have debug privilege

Comment: Interesting.
Task Manager shows PID=0 for the System Idle process.
The return code from the function is indeed 5.

Comment: no, you mistake. no such process with 0 pid. and you bad check error code - STATUS_INVALID_CID here (converted to ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)

Comment: Win7, Task Manager
System Idle Process  PID = 0, User Name = SYSTEM, Session ID = 0

I would include a screen shot, but I don't see how up post a JPG here.

Comment: noot need, System Idle Process - this is not concrete process. better double check your code. you not got access denied but how i say STATUS_INVALID_CID here (converted to ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)